# Is it possible to control sliders of darktable from tablet?

Tags: photo-editing, gimp, linux, darktable, tablet

I have a 10" android tablet and 15" laptop. Darktable and GIMP is installed on my linux laptop.

Controlling sliders/curves etc of darktable /GIMP from mouse is not efficient, for me at least.

I see the following  possibilities

1. Either I need to make shortcut for all the different sliders and somehow remember them all
2. Or I need to use tablet as control device
3. If you have something else , please share.

I would like to go with solution 2.

For image processing a touch device mainly tablet can be a killer device , if an app can do everything from gestures,double tap,single tap, multi touch, drawing and tap-hold.

I know that tablet can be used as extended display but that's not the only thing I want even though it helps to certain extent.

So basically I want to increase my image processing efficiency using tablet beyond extending the display
, is it possible ?

Comment: You might get better results with this on the Android Stack Exchange, or the Unix/Linux one. Is there something specific to Darktable or Gimp (or really, image editing in general) here?

Comment: Photo editing is the main purpose. Basicaly I want to control darktable and GIMP. On stack exchange answer is there for how to extend display using tablet. I posted here in a hope that I would get solutions optimised for image processing only.

Comment: Can you help me understand why or how image processing applications would be special in this regard?

Comment: @mattdm, I understand your concern. My idea was to eliminate general solution and stick to some specific "Photo editing" related solution like GIMP script/plugin/tool etc.In this forum I could find people who might be using some kind of tweaks in open source GIMP/Darktable similar to my needs because users of photo editors must be here if not in stackexchange. If it still doesn't make sense then I am happy to move this question from here :)

Answer (score 1):

A combination of 1 and 3 is what I do. AFAIK, there's no tablet options for darktable

Setting keyboard shortcuts for the most frequently used options, once you've pushed the keyboard shortcut for the option you can do a couple of things.

1. Pushing the mouse left/right will then adjust the curve up/down. (assuming your mouse is over the tools panel, not the image - you have to flick the mouse both ways before it starts working)
2. Typing in a number directly allows you to jump to a particular number - it takes very little time to get an intuitive feel for the numbers involved.

I find option 2 to be the most productive way of editing. I normally get the exposure adjustment correct on the first go now, and a second adjustment is very quick.